# Getting error when run springboot application in local host

Tags: spring-boot, maven, tomcat, localhost, port

When I run the application in localhost at first time it works. But I change the code and rerun it shows this error message. When I terminate all processes and rerun. Again show below messege.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.1)

2021-01-15 13:25:06.321  INFO 7180 --- [           main] com.example.demo.SocialApiApplication    : Starting SocialApiApplication using Java 15.0.1 on DESKTOP-TCH1T7S with PID 7180 (E:\springboot\SocialAPI\target\classes started by Samanthika in E:\springboot\SocialAPI)
2021-01-15 13:25:06.325  INFO 7180 --- [           main] com.example.demo.SocialApiApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-15 13:25:07.193  INFO 7180 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8006 (http)
2021-01-15 13:25:07.205  INFO 7180 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-01-15 13:25:07.205  INFO 7180 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-01-15 13:25:07.298  INFO 7180 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-01-15 13:25:07.298  INFO 7180 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 918 ms
2021-01-15 13:25:07.487  INFO 7180 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-01-15 13:25:07.676  WARN 7180 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.PortInUseException: Port 8006 is already in use
2021-01-15 13:25:07.677  INFO 7180 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-01-15 13:25:07.683  INFO 7180 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-01-15 13:25:07.700  INFO 7180 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-15 13:25:07.714 ERROR 7180 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8006 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8006 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

But I change server.port in application properties. it works. But I triedto rrun again I got above error. When I run all the time I should want to change the server port in application.properties. Is there any solution to fixed this?

Comment: It sounds like the process is not killed when you stop the application. Find the process using the port and kill it manually before restarting the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port used for your tomcat 8006 is already in use.
you need to kill the process and re-run your project

use this on your cmd to get the PID number for the proccess:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :8006
```

then kill this process using this command:

```
taskkill /PID <PID> /F
```